# Karma-Jasmine: Conflicting source files

Tags: karma-jasmine

I have a pretty nice Gulp based Karma-Jasmine unit test workflow going.  My question is about how to avoid source conflicts in one's tests.  Without having to do anything, Karma-Jasmine has auto-magically exposed my src files to Jasmine and detected my tests.  I can't see how this would be useful in a real codebase where things don't fit the happy-path.

Example: Create two files you would like to test that both implement a function with the same name, Test().  One returns true, the other false.  Which one is your test actually testing?  Do I have any control over this?  I want to be able to test both (forget telling me about better JS design, that is obvious).